# VS2012 C++ to XCode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, visual-studio-2012, cross-platform

I have written a DLL in VS2012 C++ and did not use anything fancy. 
I think I have stayed cross-platform, at least I hope so.

Can somebody tell me how to most easily get it to compile to OSX code?

I think I will have to do some manual work, but I would like to find a pipeline that would allow me to easily upgrade my application both in VS2012 and in XCode without having to write down what I changed and then do the same changes in XCode.

Perhaps I can write one interface for Windows and one for XCode and simply leave the rest of the files as they are???

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I recommend using only crossplatform UI toolkits and libraries. That way you minimize the os specific code. Also having a project generator like CMake is a big help as well. I can do all of my development in Visual Studio and without much difficulty compile using the same project file (a CMakeLists.txt) with 64 bit linux with qtcreator and gcc.

Comment: Also I believe CMake has a generator for xcode directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

1. Create a XCode project with the template: **Cocoa Touch Static Library** and add the code of the VS12 inside a folder Source.
2. Create an ObjC class to wrap your C++ code.
3. Compile the project like a static lib.
4. Add your static library with the correspond .h to your Xcode Project that will use the library.
5. Link the library with the dlyb used in your C++ code.

So you will have a VS solution and a XCode project for compile the library.

[Here](https://github.com/dcorbatta/StackoverflowTest/tree/master/CppWrapper) is a template with a UnitTest with simple C++ class and a ObjC Wrapper.

Comment: Another alternative is use Xamarin to develop mobile cross apps.

Comment: Could you be more specific about 1) ? Can I add cpp files to an XCode project?

Comment: Of course, you can, and you can create a .mm to mix objC and C++. Let me create a template.

Comment: Dear dcorbatta, thank you very much for your great reply. Just a simple side-question: I downloaded your github files one by one. Do you know if there is a download as zip function? I feel really stupid asking this, but I looked again and again, and I did not find such a function. In any case, thank you so much for your great sample!

Comment: Yes of course you can download the whole repository from the home page: https://github.com/dcorbatta/StackoverflowTest/archive/master.zip

Comment: Yes in github.com/dcorbatta/StackoverflowTest/ at the bottom right.

Comment: Not sure why I overlooked it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you perhaps interested to help me on a freelancer project? Sorry to contact you this way, I did not find your mail address right away. Please write me an email at hermie DOT weber AT gmx DOT de    if you are interested. It would be my pleasure! Thank you!